# How to change default color for displaying waves

Tags: modelsim

It seems that recently if you download the intel starter edition of modelsim, the default color of a 1 bit signal on a waveform is barely visible with "extra dark green" color against a black background...even with my laptop brightness cranked to high, its still uncomfortably dim...does anybody know how to increase the intensity of the dark-green for displaying waves signals to a higher intensity color of green for modelsim?

(I also noticed that gtkwave has the same problem as well. but simvision is still ok.)

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: In the modelsim wave window, you can change a wave color under the `Format`->`color` menu item

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to start up modelsim and make the following changes:

**(1)** Select on Menu: "Tools->Edit-Preferences". This will open up a "Preferences" Dialog box.

**(2)** In the Dialog Box, Select "Wave Windows" from "Window List" ListBox on left hand side.  This will change right hand side of dialog box to the "Wave Window Color Scheme" Listbox.

**(3)** Select "LOGIC_O" in listbox and select bright green from color palette.

**(4)** Select "LOGIC_1" in listbox and select bright green from color palette.

**(5)** Click Applied.  You can now read logic 1 and 0 because they are in bright green instead of darkgreen.

There's also a turtorial on the internet for changing your wave color scheme in modelsim here: [ModelSim timing diagram colour scheme](https://digsys.upc.edu/csd/units/EDA/ModelSim_colour_scheme.pdf)